# roscore fails at the start : error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.71.0: cannot open shared object file

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have any idea why the `roscore` fails at the start because of a strange library error? This never happened to me and it is a very strange error:

```
emanuele@emanuele-pc:~/catkin_ws$ roscore
... logging to /home/emanuele/.ros/log/314803bc-e693-11eb-8045-e7251890027b/roslaunch-emanuele-pc-37486.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://emanuele-pc:37381/
ros_comm version 1.15.11


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.11

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [37496]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://emanuele-pc:11311/

setting /run_id to 314803bc-e693-11eb-8045-e7251890027b
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [37506]
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosout/rosout: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.71.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
started core service [/rosout]
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 37506, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/emanuele/.ros/log/314803bc-e693-11eb-8045-e7251890027b/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/emanuele/.ros/log/314803bc-e693-11eb-8045-e7251890027b/rosout-1*.log
```

Thanks for shedding light on what is happening here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382686/roscore-fails-at-the-start-:-error-while-loading-shared-libraries:-libboost_thread.so.1.71.0:-cannot-open-shared-object-file/) by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2021-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-17**:\

1. What OS and version are you using?
2. What version of libboost is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks problem is solved: I have `Noetic` installed on `Ubuntu 20.04` and installed `boost` libraries from source. I uninstalled ROS and ALL instances of `boost` via `sudo apt autopurge $(dpkg -l | grep boost | grep 1.71 | awk '{print $2}')`. Re-installed ROS `Noetic` only (as it comes with the proper version of `boost 1.71`).  Now the `roscore` starts with no problem. However `catkin_make` keeps failing because of the following error `error: ‘boost::placeholders’ has not been declared`

---

Originally posted by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) with karma: 108 on 2021-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2021-07-17**:
Now the big problem is that, despite `Noetic` comes with the proper version of boost 1.71 (I checked this with `dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'` right after installing `Noetic`; to double check I also did `ldconfig -p | grep libboost`) [my previous post is my biggest concern](https://answers.ros.org/question/382677/boostplaceholders-has-not-been-declared-boostplaceholders_1/) as I am currently unable to run any project.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-17**:
It can get complicated if more than one version of libboost is installed. For a ros project, it's least confusing to just use the same version that ros itself is built with.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-17**:
I'm glad you figured it out.